# How can I limit the display height of a datalist in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, height, datalist

I have a datalist with a lot of options. When this datalist is displayed on Chrome, the height is very long, but on Firefox the datalist is displayed with a scrollbar. Anyone knows how can I solve this on Chrome?

Thanks. :)

Comment: Chrome's datalist support is crap. It just renders the list straight off your screen without providing a scroll bar. If the list is too long it crashes Desktop Window Manager on Windows. It only provided results that start with, rather than contains the text that was typed. It's completely unusable as far as I am concerned. Mozilla's behavior is exactly what any sane individual would expect. There are several bug reports open for these issues, but don't hold your breath.